# Its is related to image displaying in an HTML page

Tags: html, image, jsp, src

Display image in HTML page but my code is not working correctly I am not able to provide the URL using the src tag

If i have 
`String name=rs.getstring(picname);`

In the html image tag
`<img src="Image/"+name+">`
this not working 
name has the profile pic name
Image is a folder in the NetBeans, which contains the images

I am not getting as to how to use this variable as an url.

Comment: Can you please include your code in your question?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this

```
 <img src="Image/<c:out value="${name}"/>"
```

Be sure in that you include jstl tag library in the begining of your JSP file

```
 <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
```